# When is Sandboxed Solutions preferred in Sharepoint?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sandbox-solution

I have been referring to many articles that show comparison between SharePoint Sandboxed Solutions and Farm Solutions plus demos of Visual Web Part (Farm based) and Web Part (Sandboxed Solutions) under Visual Studio 2010 and it seems like Farm Based Development (using Visual Studio) and its deployment is far more preferred way by developers. *Correct me if I'm wrong*

Moreover,Sandboxed Solutions are restricted that Farm Solutions. Hence in what scenario a developer would preferred to develop/deploy solutions using Sandboxed way?

Answer (score 2):

Sandbox solutions is also depreciated in SP 2013 - so I won't touch them at all.

Please see e.g. http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/07/27/what-features-are-removeddepreciated-from-sharepoint-2013/ for more information.

Comment: Hence it is safe to assume that coming solutions would be more farm based as a preferred choice over the sandboxed solutions.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can have more understanding about using the sandboxed solution from the below given link.

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/SP2010Dev/Pages/SharePoint%20Sandboxed%20Solutions.aspx

In this link, there is a section for what is supported by Sandboxed solution and what is not supported by it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This far, it has never been possible to me to develop sandboxed solutions because they are too constrained for almost anything. However, if you want to use SharePoint Online (which is a SharePoint environment hosted in a Microsoft cloud), sandboxed solutions are the only way to go.

Comment: Otherwise I assume most preferred is Farm based. Correct?

Comment: At least I cannot find any usage for sandboxed solutions. Of course, they are more secure, but the problem is you cannot do very many things in them.